# Trying to add SASS to docz but docz folder keeps resetting

Tags: reactjs, sass, docz

I just started using docz and added it to an existing project. I got a component from my react folder to show up but it is missing styling so I am trying to import my SASS files into my docs.mdx file. I followed the directions on https://www.docz.site/docs/usage-with-css-preprocessors and added the below to gatsby-config.js.

```
plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-sass']
```

But everytime I run yarn docz dev, the .docz folder where I have the gatsby-config file keep getting reset and it removed the gatsby-plugin-sass line. Am I missing anything?

File structure below. (Only showing the folders and files I referenced)

```
- .docz
--- gatsby-config.js

- react
--- components
--- docs
------ docs.mdx
- styles
--- 
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem today...

You need to create a copy of the gatsby-config.js and place it in your root folder (same directory where your src folder is). This automatically creates a gatsby-config.custom.js file in your .dist folder.

Then you add 'gatsby-plugin-sass' to the plugins array of the custom JS created. This should have been installed in your package.json already.

Then run yarn docz dev and you're good to go.

Also note that you need node-sass installed in package.json